# Bordless-кнопка с заданным цветом фона

Tags: android, material-design

Мне нужна кнопка без отступов с заданным цветом фона и работающим "по умолчанию" ripple-эффектом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал сделать так:

```
<Button
            style="@style/Button.Default"
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Button.Default" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Получил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюс при нажатии вижу подсветку с отступами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: android:background="? android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"  - для рипла

Comment: @sviat-volkov, в итоге вижу ripple-эффект на пол экрана (то есть выходит за границы кнопки), с фоном такая же печалька.

Comment: уберите Borderless и будет на размер кнопки

Comment: А как быть с цветом кнопки?

Comment: ну тогда в background поставьте свой цвет, а в foreground ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground

Comment: Пробовал, не завелось. Плюс foreground, если не ошибаюсь, только с api21 работает. Попробую побаловаться с ThemeOverlay

Comment: тогда делайте не кнопку а простой лэйаут с кликом